# How can C/C++ source code and libraries be used in Java?

Tags: java, c++, c

Is there any way that a .c and .h files can be used in eclipse? On a 32 bit xp,using jre1.6. I do not know any C. The code is about 500 lines

Comment: So you want to invoke C code from Java? You need to add significantly more details to your question, because I have no clue as to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You might want to read up on [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), but it's not as simple as automagically using .c and .h files inside Java

Answer (score 2):

Not directly. You would need to know some c to add interface methods to be able to use JNI.

JNI is the key to use c or c++ code.

Answer (score 1):

You can either invoke it using JNA or JNI, JNA generally being the easier one to use.

You'll need to alter your code though by reading up on the two technologies - it's not a magic bullet.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to rewrite the code.

Any kind of automated conversion usually produces unmaintainable code. If you opt for this solution, just pick one of these :
http://tech.novosoft-us.com/product_c2j.jsp
http://www.soften.ktu.lt/~stonis/c2java/